# How to get elements from a webpage DOM into my background.js?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I`m trying to make an extension for Chrome that automatically logs in to [this](https://vaf.itslearning.com/elogin/) web page. It does this by detecting when I enter the page, then it redirects the browser to the login page, where it fills in the username and password and clicks the login button.

manifest.json:

```
{
    "manifest_version": 2,

    "name": "Login",
    "description": "Automaticly logs in to a page",
    "version": "1.0",
    "background": {
        "scripts": ["background.js"],
        "persistent": false
    },

    "permissions": [
        "tabs",
        "http://*/"
    ]
}
```

background.js:

```
window.onload = function() {
    chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function(tabId, changeInfo, tab){
        if (tab.url == "https://www.itslearning.com/Index.aspx?customerid=&username=&redirectlogin=itslearning.com&MustUseSsl=true&") {
            chrome.tabs.update(tabId, {"url": "https://vaf.itslearning.com/elogin/"}, function(){});
        } else if(tab.url == "https://vaf.itslearning.com/elogin/") {
            var username = document.getElementById("ctl00_Username"); //doesn't work
            var password = document.getElementById("ctl00_Password"); //doesn't work
            var button = document.getElementById("ctl00_ButtonLogin"); //doesn't work
            if (username && password && button) {
                username.value = "####";
                password.value = "######";
                button.click();
            }
        }
    });
};
```

I got the id for the fields by right clicking -> inspect element in chrome. When I first ran it, it redirected the browser to the correct page, but it didn't fill in the password and username, so I did some quick debugging, and seems like it's never able to find any of the fields. I searched around the forum, and found out that the page had to be fully loaded first, so I added `window.onload=function(){}` but it still doesn't work. Why?

I'm have programmed a little in javascript before, but I'm new to chrome extension development, so if anyone has some additional tips or suggestions, please share them with me.

Comment: So when you put a breakpoint at `document.getElementById("ctl00_Username")` - it returns `null`?

Comment: Also, instead of `window.onload = function() {...}` can you try `Sys.Application.add_load(function() {...});` ?

Comment: @YuriyGalanter if I remove the if statement `if (username && password && button)` it gives me this error: `Cannot call method 'value' of null`, if that answers your question. I tried adding `Sys.Application.add_load(function() {...});` but then it didn't work at all

Comment: I think you maybe confusing jquery calls with standard JS. Instead of `username.val("####"); password.val("######");` try `username.value = "####"; password.value = "######";`

Comment: @YuriyGalanter yes, i noticed that, but i tried changing it and it still doesn't work

Comment: When you examinge `username` variable after `document.getElementById("ctl00_Username")` call - what value does it hold? You can check it by putting breakpoint in JS code

Comment: looking at the DOM info for the username field and that id is actually `ctl00$Username`.  the label for that input is `ctl00_Username`. maybe you're not getting a `value` because your ID is pointing you to the `label` which has no value attribute.

Comment: @YuriyGalanter it looks like the value is `NULL`

Comment: @b_dubb `ctl00$Username` is the name, not the id. i tried it just to be sure, and it didn't work either

Comment: i would avoid using `$`. if you use prototype.js or jquery.js you'll probably break everything

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Background scripts can't interact directly with the DOM of regular pages. When you use `document` in a background script, you are referring to the DOM of the background page that Google Chrome creates for your extension.

To access the DOM of web pages you need a [content script](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts.html). You can specify it in the manifest or inject it programmatically using `chrome.tabs.executeScript`. As in your case you want to always run it in a specific URL the easiest way is via the manifest:

```
"content_scripts": [
  {
    "matches": ["https://vaf.itslearning.com/elogin/"],
    "js": ["content.js"]
  }
],
```

And in your content.js you can put:

```
var username = document.getElementById("ctl00_Username");
var password = document.getElementById("ctl00_Password");
var button = document.getElementById("ctl00_ButtonLogin");
if (username && password && button) {
   username.value = "####";
   password.value = "######";
   button.click();
}
```

So in your background.js you only need to leave the redirect code:

```
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function(tabId, changeInfo, tab) {
    if (tab.url == "https://www.itslearning.com/Index.aspx?customerid=&username=&redirectlogin=itslearning.com&MustUseSsl=true&")
        chrome.tabs.update(tabId, {"url": "https://vaf.itslearning.com/elogin/"});
}
```

(BTW, there are more efficient ways to cause a redirect using `chrome.webRequest`)