# "chrome.tabs.update" can be use in IE (is there a similar code for IE) with javascript?

Tags: javascript, dom, element

In a question, I saw people reach to web site's element with Chrome that using Javascript.

It was a big problem for me that get a element from a web site and simulate that. I create  2 question for that but I couldn't reach a answer clearly.

So my firs question was ; [click a button on a web site automatically with javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42366228/click-a-button-on-a-web-site-automatically-with-javascript)

My second question was : [How can I create a code with Javascript which Automatically click buttons on a web site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42360504/how-can-i-create-a-code-with-javascript-which-automaticaly-click-buttons-on-a-we)

Now I reached a lot of method and tried,  found a success process like : [How to get elements from a webpage DOM into my background.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19054299/how-to-get-elements-from-a-webpage-dom-into-my-background-js)

After that point I want to ask "How Can I use a code to get element from IE browser. In this tag there was a code like  "chrome.tabs.update". Is there any element that using get code from IE like that which similar to chrome method's.

And If I follow that method Can I access a element (Button,Textbutton or Check Button) to click Automatically?

That code taken from this title : [How to get elements from a webpage DOM into my background.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19054299/how-to-get-elements-from-a-webpage-dom-into-my-background-js)

```
"content_scripts": [
  {
    "matches": ["https://vaf.itslearning.com/elogin/"],
    "js": ["content.js"]
  }
],

var username = document.getElementById("ctl00_Username");
var password = document.getElementById("ctl00_Password");
var button = document.getElementById("ctl00_ButtonLogin");
if (username && password && button) {
   username.value = "####";
   password.value = "######";
   button.click();
}

chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function(tabId, changeInfo, tab) {
    if (tab.url == "https://www.itslearning.com/Index.aspx?customerid=&username=&redirectlogin=itslearning.com&MustUseSsl=true&")
        chrome.tabs.update(tabId, {"url": "https://vaf.itslearning.com/elogin/"});
}
```